# How to force Flush tee in linux

Tags: csh

I'm trying to print the latest 3 logfiles which are generated from csh script:

```
<my_command> | tee $FULL_PATH/logs/${verifyFileName}_${TIME_STAMP}.log
```

The problem is when I print the files, the latest log files weren't yet generated, is there a way to flush tee?

Comment: `<my_command>` is long-running and there are multiple active instances at the same time, right? And you're trying to check the logs of instances of `<my_command>` which haven't yet finished executing, but the logs haven't been generated although you assume the instances of `<my_command>` have already produced output, is that correct?

Comment: Anyway I think this addresses your exact problem : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401956/how-do-i-unbuffer-the-output-passed-from-an-interactive-command-into-a-pipeline

Comment: Regarding to question 1 , I think the instances has finished since I'm using subprocess.call  in python 
code:
  for filenames in os.listdir(directory):
                 my_f = os.path.join(directory, filenames)
                 subprocess.call(['./scr/run_batch_mode_session_option.csh %s %s %s %s ' %(DPXOption,sessionFile,my_f,parent_dir)],shell=True)
              the log files are generated from the script : run_batch_mode_session_option.csh which contains the tee command : | tee  $FULL_PATH/logs/${verifyFileName}_${TIME_STAMP}.log

Comment: If the script terminates I doubt it's a buffering problem. What did you mean by "the latest log files weren't yet generated"in your question, does waiting for a few minutes make the files appear? If so, I would think the command producing the logs is still running and the problem doesn't lie with tee